# authorizing users with cancan and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, authorization, cancan

I have a user model created with Devise that has an admin boolean field and a roles integer field. I am trying to create an ability class that allows a non admin user to have certain abilities based on roles, but am having issues with this process. I have created an authorized controller as such:

```
class AuthorizedController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate_user!
 check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?
 load_and_authorize_resource

 rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  flash[:alert] = exception.message
  redirect_to root_url
 end

end

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if !user
    can  :read, :all
  end

  if user 
    admin_rules if user.admin?
    commenter_rules if user.role.equal?("1")
    author_rules if user.role.equal?("2")
  end     
end

  def admin_rules
    can :manage, :all
  end

  def commenter_rules
    can :manage, Data, :active => true, :user_id => user.id
  end

  def author_rules
    can :manage, Post, :active => true, :user_id => user.id
  end 
end
```

Now whenever I try to access any pages, It throws the exception message "You are not authorized to access this page." instead of being able to access that part of the website.

Comment: Can you post the error with a backtrace?

Comment: Where is the `:active` attribute coming from, Devise?

Comment: hard to help without the actual exception message

Comment: sorry, it is "You are not authorized to access this page."

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling `cancan` is working correctly.  Try debugging this way:

1. Temporarily take out the `check_authorization`
2. Add a few lines to your view to see what abilities you do have:

   ```
   %h1 What abilities do I have?
   %ul
     %li can?(:manage, Data)
     %li can?(:manage, :all)
     %li etc..
   ```